# Why 405 method not allowed error occur in wcf?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

This is my class

```
[DataContract()]
    public class Test
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

    }
```

this is my svc.cs page function

```
public string Testpost(Test T)
        {
            string User_name;
            User_name = T.UserName;

            DataUtility du = new DataUtility();

            string[] Parameters = new string[2] { "@UserName", "@Result" };
            string[] DbTypes = new string[2] { "varchar", "varchar" };
            string[] ParameterTypes = new string[2] { "input", "Output" };
            string[] values = new string[2] { User_name, "" };
            string[] Lengths = new string[2] { "100", "50" };


            String Praveen = du.executeNonQuerry(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "InsertTest", Parameters, DbTypes, ParameterTypes, values, Lengths);

            if (Praveen == "1")
            {
                return "Insertion Success";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Failed Insertion";
            }


        }
```

and this is my uri Template

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/Testpost")]
        string Testpost(Test T);
```

and this is my config

```
<service name="SkyService.Customer" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SkyService.ICustomer" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" bindingConfiguration="WCFServiceBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
```

and i access post method via j query ajax like as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () { 
             //var param = {"UserName":"Praveen"};

            var _Name = { "T": { "UserName": "LC" } };
            $.support.cors = true;
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "http://203.124.96.81/Track/Customer.svc/TestPost",

                 //data: {"UserName":"Praveen"},
                 //contentType: "application/json",
                 //dataType: 'jsonp',

                 data: JSON.stringify(_Name),
              returncallback: false,
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 dataType: "jsonp",


                 success: function (data) {
                     alert(data.Text);
                     console.log(data);

                 },
                 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     //alert(XMLHttpRequest+" "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
                     console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                     console.log(textStatus);
                     console.log(errorThrown);

                 }
             });
         })

    </script>
```

the service get result in localhost and insertion of data in database is successfull , but when i use it through remotely then error comes which is **METHOD NOT ALLOWED**???? how to do this???

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a cross domain issue.

Please follow instruction in http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wcf/X8QN260412-Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-Service-using-Jquery.html

and try it.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If my answer works please set it as a answer to a question so nobody tries to solve this issue.

Comment: my service get correct result on Mozilla but i have checked today it is not responded on IE and Chrome....